# loop for part of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

I've done a multistep form in PHP storing the data in a multidimensional array (I've created an array inside `$_SESSION` array and named it `$_SESSION['inserimento'])`

then i have `$_SESSION['inserimento']['name'],$_SESSION['inserimento']['city']`...

I would like to apply the `strtolower()` function to all the values before adding them to mysql

I've tried this code but it doesn't work

```
foreach ($_SESSION['inserimento'] as $k=>$v){
    $v=strtolower($v);
}
```

I think I'm misunderstanding how to make a loop on multidimensional array.

Comment: try var_dump($_SESSION['inserimento']); before the foreach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [array_map()](https://www.php.net/array_map) to apply a function to all elements in an array:

```
$_SESSION['inserimento'] = array_map('strtolower', $_SESSION['inserimento']);
```

Or a regular foreach loop (inside the loop `$v` is a copy, so you need to affect to the original array):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['inserimento'] as $k => $v) {
  $_SESSION['inserimento'][$k] = strtolower($v);
}
```

Or a foreach loop with reference (`$v` is no longer a copy, it is a reference to the original element):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['inserimento'] as &$v) {
  $v = strtolower($v);
}
unset($v); // remember to unset, or $v will still be a reference to the last element after the loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['inserimento'] as $k => $v) {
    $_SESSION['inserimento'][$k] = strtolower($v);
}
```

This is happening because `$v` is a copy of the value inside the iteration, not a reference to the variable that contains the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a variable defined outside of the `foreach loop`.

```
$lowerValue = '';
foreach ($_SESSION['inserimento'] as $k => $v) {
    $lowerValue = strtolower($v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-walk.php)

```php
array_walk($_SESSION['inserimento'], function(&$value, $key) {
    $value = strtolower($value);
});
```

The `&` before `$value` indicates that the variable is passed by reference.